# como fazer um loop com prompt em javascript?

Tags: javascript, prompt

```
     let nomePessoa = prompt('Digite o nome da  pessoa ');
     let idadePessoa = prompt(`Digite a idade de ${nomePessoa}`);
     let alturaPessoa = prompt(`Digite a altura de ${nomePessoa}`);
     let registreOutraPessoa = prompt('Deseja registrar outra pessoa? (S/N)');

     let pessoa = [nomePessoa, idadePessoa, alturaPessoa, registreOutraPessoa]

     if (pessoa.registreOutraPessoa != 'N'){
        let nomePessoa = prompt('Digite o nome da  pessoa ');
        let idadePessoa = prompt(`Digite a idade de ${nomePessoa}`);
        let alturaPessoa = prompt(`Digite a altura de ${nomePessoa}`);
     
    } else{

         
     }
```

Comment: Pesquise por `for` ou `while` no JavaScript. Poderá utilizá-los para criar o laço de repetição que precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo usando while:

```
function GetPessoas(){


let pessoas = [];

let registreOutraPessoa = 'S';

while ( registreOutraPessoa !== 'N' )
{
  let nomePessoa =  prompt('Digite o nome da  pessoa ');
  let idadePessoa = prompt(`Digite a idade de ${nomePessoa}`);
  let alturaPessoa = prompt(`Digite a altura de ${nomePessoa}`);
  registreOutraPessoa = prompt('Deseja registrar outra pessoa? (S/N)');

  let pessoa = [nomePessoa, idadePessoa, alturaPessoa, registreOutraPessoa]
  pessoas.push(pessoa);
}

  console.log(pessoas);
  return pessoas;
}
```